Remove parts of substring with couple of conditions
how can I "clean" strings from everything that starts with GH until - mark, I need just the rest of the data, the problem is that I don't know what number will be part of GHxxx-,GHxx- in the example, it can be anything.
Is there a way in regex to define something like this?
GH8-30476E/30477E
GH82-23124B GH82-23100B
GH82-20900Aaa, GH82-20838A
GH82-20900C,GH82-20838C
GH962-13566A
GH82-23596C/23597C/31461C

desired result:
30476E 30477E
23124B 23100B
20900Aaa 20838A
20900C 20838C
13566A
23596C 23597C 31461C



const arr = ["GH8-30476E/30477E", "GH82-23124B GH82-23100B", "GH82-20900Aaa, GH82-20838A", "GH82-20900C,GH82-20838C", "GH962-13566A", "GH82-23596C/23597C/31461C"]

arr.forEach((e, index) => {
  arr[index] = e.replace(/GH82-/gi, '');


})
console.log(arr)



Thank you in advance.
edit:
GH82-23100B can be GH82-2310044B  or GH82-23B, that is why my approach was to remove GH, not match the other 5 characters.
edit2:
I edited the examples a bit. Looks like solution from comment works

You have the regex tag in your question. So why aren't you using a regular expression? Do you not know how to write a regex that matches any set of digits?

@Barmar yes I don't know how. I have used it inside replace /GH82/gi, but I don't know how to write all the conditions and I can not find it on the web for all the use cases I need, i edited my post. Also answer does not necessarily have to be in regex, but I belive it is the best way.

\d for a numeric digit, {n,m} for range eg \d{1,2} to match 1 or 2 digits, + for 1 or more \d+ same as \d{1,}

Sounds like you need to read a tutorial on regular expressions. This is a really basic pattern.

e.replace(/GH\d*-/gi, '').split(/\W+/).join(" ")?

@WiktorStribiżew Seems right from testing :)

You can use


const arr = ["GH82-30476E/30477E", "GH82-23124B GH82-23100B", "GH82-20900A, GH82-20838A", "GH82-20900C,GH82-20838C", "GH962-13566A", "GH82-23596C/23597C/31461C"]

arr.forEach((e, index) => {
  arr[index] = e.replace(/GH\d*-/gi, '').split(/\W+/).join(" ");


})
console.log(arr)



Here

.replace(/GH\d*-/gi, '') - removes GH + zero or more digits and then -
.split(/\W+/) - splits at non-word chars
.join(" ") - joins the resulting items with a space.


You can use regex with some string manipulation using replace.
Here’s an example:
const arr = [
    "GH8-30476E/30477E",
    "GH82-23124B GH82-23100B",
    "GH82-20900Aaa, GH82-20838A",
    "GH82-20900C,GH82-20838C",
    "GH962-13566A",
    "GH82-23596C/23597C/31461C"
];

const result = arr.map(str => {
    // Replace everything before and including the hyphen with an empty string
    // Replace commas and slashes with spaces
    return str.replace(/.*-(.*)/, '$1')
              .replace(/[,\/]/g, ' ')
              .trim();
});

console.log(result);

/* OUTPUT:
[
    "30476E 30477E",
    "23124B 23100B",
    "20900Aaa 20838A",
    "20900C 20838C",
    "13566A",
    "23596C 23597C 31461C"
]
*/

How it works?
Regex to Remove Prefix: str.replace(/.*-(.*)/, '$1')
This regex captures everything after the hyphen (-). The .- part matches all characters up to the last hyphen, and (.) captures the remaining part.
Replace Commas and Slashes: .replace(/[,\/]/g, ' ')
This replaces commas and slashes with spaces.
Trim Extra Spaces: .trim()
This removes any leading or trailing spaces from the resulting string. When you run this code, you will get the cleaned-up output (see above example).


You could just get the output and ignore everything else:



const regex = /[0-9]{5}[A-Z]/gm;
const arr = [
  "GH82-30476E/30477E",
  "GH82-23124B GH82-23100B",
  "GH82-20900A, GH82-20838A",
  "GH82-20900C,GH82-20838C",
  "GH962-13566A",
  "GH82-23596C/23597C/31461C",
];

let res = [];

arr.forEach((str) => {
  const M = str.match(regex);
  if (M) {
    res.push(M.join(" "));
  }
});

console.log(res);





If you have to remove those unwanted patterns, you can use \s*[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{1,3}\s*-\s*|[\/,.], instead:



const regex = /\s*[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{1,3}\s*-\s*|[\/,.]/gm;
const arr = [
  "GH82-30476E/30477E",
  "GH82-23124B GH82-23100B",
  "GH82-20900A, GH82-20838A",
  "GH82-20900C,GH82-20838C",
  "GH962-13566A",
  "GH82-23596C/23597C/31461C",
];

let res = [];

arr.forEach((str) => {
  let s = str.replace(regex, " ");
  s = s.replace(/\s{2,}/g, " ").trim();
  res.push(s);
});

console.log(res);




You can add more restrictions to the pattern, depending on how your data may look like:
/\s*\b[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{1,3}\b\s*-\s*|[\/,.]+/g


[\/,.]+, anything that wanted to be removed, goes into this character class.

\b, is a word boundary.




If we only have GH, then we simply use: /\s*\bGH[0-9]{1,3}\b\s*-\s*|[\/,.]+/g


His, thank you for answering, did you match the number of characters in the result to 5? That is also unknown I'm afraid, that is what I want to remove gh xx-

the one solution does not work if you have "GH962-135665A", other one if you have "GH9-" for examle

it does not work with GH535445- or GH-

@ikiK Try /\s*\bGH[0-9]*\b\s*-\s*|[\/,.]+/g

that works, thanks a lot for helping with examples. I except first one as it just looks "simpler"

Just replace 2 times:
arr.map(e => e.replace(/GH\w+\W+?/g, '').replace(/\W+/g, ' '));

` Chrome/125
-------------------------------------------------
Alexander  ■ 1.00x | x1000000 844 846 848 852 881
Wiktor       1.34x |  x100000 113 117 122 125 127
------------------------------------------------- `

Open in the playground


const arr = ["GH82-30476E/30477E", "GH82-23124B GH82-23100B", "GH82-20900A, GH82-20838A", "GH82-20900C,GH82-20838C", "GH962-13566A", "GH82-23596C/23597C/31461C"]

// @benchmark Alexander
arr.map(e => e.replace(/GH\w+\W+?/g, '').replace(/\W+/g, ' '));

// @benchmark Wiktor
arr.map(e => e.replace(/GH\d*-/gi, '').split(/\W+/).join(" "));

/*@skip*/ fetch('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js').then(r => r.text().then(eval));




There are two way you did that.
Method-01: find matched substring of format \d{5}[A-Z] and then join them.
Method-02: remove GH\d+\- substring and / or , special characters, then trim the data.
Code as follows:


const arr = [
  "GH82-30476E/30477E",
  "GH82-23124B GH82-23100B",
  "GH82-20900A, GH82-20838A",
  "GH82-20900C,GH82-20838C",
  "GH962-13566A",
  "GH82-23596C/23597C/31461C",
];

// Method-01
console.log('Method-01: ', arr.map(x => x.match(/\d{5}[A-Z]/gi).join(' ')));

// Method-02
console.log('Method-02: ', arr.map(x => x.replace(/(GH\d+\-)|([\/\,])/gi, ' ')
                      .trim().replace(/\s+/g, ' '))); 



